# Can I get a command block on Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was just wondering if you could get a command block in Minecraft PE.

Comment: Without the use of mods/hacks, nope :/

Answer (score 2):

Command blocks are not in Pocket Edition as of this date. You can find a [list of all things available in Minecraft PE on the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition#Content).

Answer (score 1):

No. It does not even exist in PE. You could use redstone comparators though

Comment: What do comparators have to do with command blocks?

Comment: @MrLemon There have been some smart contraptions made in PE that use comparators

Comment: @GuynamedJon proof?

Comment: @Alex Seems like this guy did it with only Minecart with chests and comparators although it is in the computer version http://pinneast.com/video/watch/id17UjXXg8tcvuI

Answer (score 0):

It is currently impossible to get Command Blocks in MCPE without a mod. Command Blocks wont come out in 0.16.0 either. If you want command blocks, check out this mod: http://mcpedl.com/command-blocks/

Answer (score 0):

As of the latest update, Command blocks are avaliable in Minecraft PE.
You will have to enter this command in the chat:

`/give [player] command_block [amount]`

People who cannot use the `/give` command cannot get a Command Block.

If you also want a Command Block in a Minecart put `“_minecart”` at the end of `“command_block”` without any spaces.

To test it, try putting a command in it, like gamemode. Then activate the block to test it.

If this depends on devices you’re using I have not searched up that yet. It worked for me on iPad.

Comment: It actually appears [1.0.5 added them](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Update_1.0.5)